# Using Einstein Activity Capture, unable to show Mails and Events in custom components

Tags: einstein, activities, einstein-activity-capture

We have Einstein Activity Capture activated in our Org. We want the synced events and mail to be part of our custom component.
Since these records are not stored in Salesforce we are not able to show them in custom component.

As per this help document (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_event_considerations.htm&type=5) when **Related synced events to Salesforce records** setting is on, the events get added automatically to the activity timeline of related account, contact, and lead records. The events on the timeline are Salesforce records and are available in standard reports and other Salesforce Platform capabilities. In our Org this setting is ON but all events are stored as Salesforce records.

As per the EAC documentation, the emails and events are stored in SF AWS servers. They are fetched from there and displayed in the activity timeline of the related Contact, Leads etc. We want to show emails in our custom components.

***Are there any API available where we can fetch the emails and events from AWS server, store them in SF and the show in our custom components?***

Comment: I'd like to further understand the use case that you have here on your custom components and exposing emails from EAC, as we are working to prioritize some of these capabilities in the coming releases.

Comment: @VanessaChalem could I also throw in a request to be able to find the "max" scheduled date of an event, regardless of SF Event vs EAC Event so we can watch for gaps in our customer success motion and prioritize contact.

Comment: Ever figure out any solution for this? I'm also intrigued, trying to figure out how to determine the latest-scheduled event, regardless of source-of-origin for the event.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein Activity Capture does not insert emails from connected users to the org data layer. It creates a custom index and renders those emails and events to the end user on page load for the contextual Contact, Account, Opportunity object records where the sending/receiving email is matched.

Salesforce Inbox, Mixmax and other email sync clients are needed to expose a custom solution since those products insert to the email tables and consume data space.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_guidelines.htm&type=5

From the General Section:

> General
>
> - When emails move from the connected account to Salesforce, they don’t become Salesforce records and aren’t available in standard reports and other Salesforce platform capabilities.